# Error throwing on Target CPU: x86

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I got a problem with this function i use to retrieve the product key from my computer.

```
    Public Function GetProductKey(ByVal KeyPath As String, ByVal ValueName As String) As String
    Dim HexBuf As Object = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(KeyPath, ValueName, 0)
    If HexBuf Is Nothing Then Return "N/A"
    Dim tmp As String = String.Empty

    For l As Integer = LBound(CType(HexBuf, Array)) To UBound(CType(HexBuf, Array))
        tmp = tmp & " " & Hex(CByte(AscW(HexBuf.ToString(1))))
    Next

    Dim StartOffset As Integer = 52
    Dim EndOffset As Integer = 67
    Dim Digits(24) As String

    Digits(0) = "B" : Digits(1) = "C" : Digits(2) = "D" : Digits(3) = "F"
    Digits(4) = "G" : Digits(5) = "H" : Digits(6) = "J" : Digits(7) = "K"
    Digits(8) = "M" : Digits(9) = "P" : Digits(10) = "Q" : Digits(11) = "R"
    Digits(12) = "T" : Digits(13) = "V" : Digits(14) = "W" : Digits(15) = "X"
    Digits(16) = "Y" : Digits(17) = "2" : Digits(18) = "3" : Digits(19) = "4"
    Digits(20) = "6" : Digits(21) = "7" : Digits(22) = "8" : Digits(23) = "9"

    Dim dLen As Integer = 29
    Dim sLen As Integer = 15
    Dim HexDigitalPID(15) As String
    Dim Des(30) As String
    Dim tmp2 As String = String.Empty


    Dim notbuffer As Array = CType(HexBuf, Array)

    For i = StartOffset To EndOffset
        HexDigitalPID(i - StartOffset) = notbuffer.GetValue(i).ToString
        tmp2 = tmp2 & " " & Hex(HexDigitalPID(i - StartOffset))
    Next

    Dim KEYSTRING As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = dLen - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ((i + 1) Mod 6) = 0 Then
            Des(i) = "-"
            KEYSTRING = KEYSTRING & "-"
        Else
            Dim HN As Integer = 0
            For N As Integer = (sLen - 1) To 0 Step -1
                Dim Value As Integer = CInt(CLng((HN * 2 ^ 8)) Or CLng(HexDigitalPID(N)))
                HexDigitalPID(N) = (Value \ 24).ToString
                HN = (Value Mod 24)
            Next
            Des(i) = Digits(HN)
            KEYSTRING = KEYSTRING & Digits(HN)
        End If
    Next
    Return StrReverse(KEYSTRING)
End Function
```

This works well if i compile using x64 or AnyCPU architecture, but if i put x86 (which is what i want) it throws me this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtxlY.png

It says: "Cannot associate the object type System.Int32 to System.Array"
I can't figure out the problem, i can't do a for Next with that arguments?
Why this works with x64 and AnyCPU (Still x64 since i got a 64-bit OS) and not x86?

Thanks.

Comment: A 32-bit process is redirected to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  Which doesn't have the key you are looking for so you now get the default value you pass.  0, an Integer.  Compile to AnyCPU or use RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey()

Comment: Oh okay, i never stumbled upon regedit calls being redirected, good to know, the thing is, without Compiling to AnyCPU i don't have much choice because i'm not compiling with framework 4.0 + (Which is what that function requires, i'm using 3.0.
I'm already searching to find a way without changing the framework too...
Thank you.